# Convert List<A> to Map<B,List<A>>

Tags: collections, lambda, java-8

```
class Student{
    String name;
    String grade;
    String vocationalSubject;
}

class Vocational{
    String grade;
    String vocationalSubject;
}
```

I want to convert `List<Student>` to `Map<Vocational,List<Student>>` using java 8 lambdas.

If I have Vocational as a member of Student, then I can do like :
    `students.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getVocational))`

As I do not have `Vocational` as a member of `Student`, I need to create it using `Vocational::new` But I am not sure how to set those two fields(`grade` and `vocationalSubject`) from `Student` in `Vocational`.

Trying to Do it using Java 8 Lambdas

Comment: Ok and what are you stuck on? Did you read the Stream tutorial? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/ Could you also give a sample input / output?

Comment: I was referring to [this example](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/). If I have Vocational as a member of Student, then I can do like :
    `students.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getVocational))`


But When it is not, I need to create object of that class and then populate it with grade and vocationalSubject.

Not sure how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have implemented `equals` and `hashCode` methods correctly, then you can create `Vocational` objects in the `groupingBy` function.

```
Map<Vocational, List<Student>> mapping = students.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(s -> new Vocational(s.getGrade(), s.getVocationalSubject()))
    );
```

Comment: Thank you Flown.
This is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

May not be perfect but this should be close to what you are looking for. This will work even if you have not overridden "equals" method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Student
{

    String name;
    String grade;
    String vocationalSubject;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getVocationalSubject() {
        return vocationalSubject;
    }

    public void setVocationalSubject(String vocationalSubject) {
        this.vocationalSubject = vocationalSubject;
    }



    Student(String name,String grade,String vocSub)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.grade=grade;
        this.vocationalSubject=vocSub;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", grade=" + grade + ", vocationalSubject=" + vocationalSubject + "]";
    }
}

class Vocational
{
    String grade;
    String vocationalSubject;

    public Vocational(String grade, String vocationalSubject) {
        this.grade = grade;
        this.vocationalSubject = vocationalSubject;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vocational [grade=" + grade + ", vocationalSubject=" + vocationalSubject + "]";
    }

}

public class Temp 
{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Map<Vocational,List<Student>> map=new HashMap<Vocational,List<Student>>();
        List<Student> listStu=new ArrayList<Student>();
        listStu.add(new Student("Student1","100","aa"));
        listStu.add(new Student("Student1","100","bb"));
        listStu.add(new Student("Student2","50","aa"));
        listStu.add(new Student("Student2","50","bb"));
        listStu.add(new Student("Student3","100","aa"));
        listStu.add(new Student("Student3","50","bb"));
        listStu.add(new Student("Student4","50","aa"));
        listStu.add(new Student("Student4","100","bb"));

        listStu.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade,Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getVocationalSubject)))
        .forEach((k,v)->v.forEach((x,y)->map.put(new Vocational(k, x), y)));

        map.forEach((x,y)->System.out.println(x+":"+y));
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Chirag,
Thanks for the new approach and the code snippet.